# Правильность оформления sql запроса

Tags: php, sql

Как правильно оформить sql запрос, который содержит php переменные (скобки, кавыйки, апострофы, точки, и т.д.)?

```
$do="UPDATE $table SET cena=$cena WHERE id=$id";
@mysql_query($do, $mv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$do="UPDATE $table SET cena=$cena WHERE id=$id";
@mysql_query($do, $mv);
```

формировать запрос можно по разному, в зависимости от параметров, пока дело дойдет до соединения всего запроса, можно будет долго и упорно проверять все значения и подставлять их в конечную переменную которая и будет вызвана

допустим так.

```
$do="UPDATE ".$table." SET cena='".$cena."' WHERE id='".$id."'";

@mysql_query($do, $mv); // и что помогает такая запись с @? может лучше использовать проверку на ошибки?
```

Comment: @ вообще смысла в данном случае не имеет - mysql_query не выдает сообщений и предупреждений. Если запрос ошибочен, просто вернет false.

Comment: хм. ты хочешь сказать что при неправильном запросе mysql_query не вернет ошибку? ну ребята вам виднее. удачи на поприще неудачных обработок ошибок.

Comment: При неправильном запросе mysql_query вернет false. И не более. Читайте справку хоть иногда.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы настоятельно рекомендовал использовать [подготовленные запросы](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php). Особенно это оправдано для борьбы с [sql-инъекциями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) в случаях, когда запрос формируется с использованием данных, полученных из ненадежных источников (например, пользовательский ввод из отправленной, на HTTP-сервер, формы с данными).

Вот переписанный пример запроса, с использованием подготовленного запроса (обработка ошибок опущена для краткости, только суть):

```
$do = "UPDATE $table SET cena=? WHERE id=?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $do);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "di", $cena, $id);
mysql_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$do="UPDATE $table SET cena=".$cena." WHERE id=".$id."";
```